# Images on RecyclerView does not updated after Image url changed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am sending Request on fragment to receive Store Item data from Server which contains urls of images like below

```
public class StoreFragment extends BaseFragment<FragmentStoreBinding, StoreViewModel> implements StoreNavigator {

    @Inject
    StoreViewModel viewModel;
    @Inject
    StoreAdapter storeAdapter;
    @Inject
    StoreVO storeVO;

    public static final String TAG = StoreFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private FragmentStoreBinding binding;

    public static StoreFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        StoreFragment fragment = new StoreFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public static StoreFragment newInstance(StoreVO storeVO) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        StoreFragment fragment = new StoreFragment();
        args.putString(INTENT_EXTRA_STOREVO, new Gson().toJson(storeVO)); //put string, int, etc in bundle with a key value
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBindingVariable() {
        return BR.viewModel;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.fragment_store;
    }

    @Override
    public StoreViewModel getViewModel() {
        return viewModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void goBack() {
        getBaseActivity().onFragmentDetached(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewModel.setNavigator(this);
        storeAdapter.setStoreFragment(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        binding = getViewDataBinding();

        if (getArguments().containsKey(INTENT_EXTRA_STOREVO)) {
            storeVO = new Gson().fromJson(getArguments().getString(INTENT_EXTRA_STOREVO), StoreVO.class);
        }
        initView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrefClicked(String prefSn, boolean sendRequest) {
        storeVO.setPrefSn(prefSn);
        storeVO.setSearchKeyCode1(prefSn);

        switch (prefSn) {
            case EAT_PREF_SN:
                binding.eatCb.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case DRINK_PREF_SN:
                binding.drinkCb.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case PLAY_PREF_SN:
                binding.playCb.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case WATCH_PREF_SN:
                binding.watchCb.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case WALK_PREF_SN:
                binding.walkCb.setChecked(true);
                break;
            default:
                binding.allCb.setChecked(true);
        }

        if(sendRequest){
            //initStoreView();
            viewModel.requestStoreList(storeVO);
        }
    }

    private void initView() {
        binding.storeRv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 2));
        binding.storeRv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        binding.storeRv.setAdapter(storeAdapter);
        initStoreView();
        onPrefClicked(storeVO.getPrefSn(), false);
    }

    private void initStoreView(){
        viewModel.requestStoreList(storeVO);
        subscribeStoreListLiveData();
    }

    private void subscribeStoreListLiveData() {
        viewModel.getStoreListLiveData().observe(this, storeList -> {
            viewModel.addStoreList(storeList);
            if (storeList != null) {
                binding.totalCount.setText(String.valueOf(storeList.size()));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

view model for this fragment is like below

```
public class StoreViewModel extends BaseViewModel<StoreNavigator> {

public final ObservableList<StoreVO> storeObservableList = new ObservableArrayList<>();
// MutableLiveData는 LifeCycle에 의존하여 메모리관리 등 여러 장점을 지님
private final MutableLiveData<List<StoreVO>> storeListLiveData;

public StoreViewModel(BaseApplication baseApplication) {
    super(baseApplication);
    storeListLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
}

public void requestStoreList(StoreVO storeVO) {
    getCompositeDisposable().add(
            getRetrofitService().selectStoreInfoList(storeVO)
                    .subscribeOn(getNetworkHelper().getSchedulerIo())
                    .observeOn(getNetworkHelper().getSchedulerUi())
                    .subscribe(storeListLiveData::setValue, throwable -> Dlog.e(throwable.getMessage())));
}

public MutableLiveData<List<StoreVO>> getStoreListLiveData() {
    return storeListLiveData;
}

public void addStoreList(List<StoreVO> storeList) {
    storeObservableList.clear();
    storeObservableList.addAll(storeList);
}

public ObservableList<StoreVO> getStoreObservableList() {
    return storeObservableList;
}

public void onFilterClick() {
    getNavigator().goToSearchFilterActivity();
}

public void onPrefTypeClicked(String prefSn) {
    getNavigator().onPrefClicked(prefSn, true);
}
```

}

and storeList was attached by adapter like below

```
public class StoreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StoreAdapter.StoreViewHolder> {

private List<StoreVO> storeList;
private StoreFragment storeFragment;

public StoreAdapter() {
    this.storeList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public StoreViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    StoreItemListBinding binding = StoreItemListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
    return new StoreViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StoreViewHolder holder, int index) {
    final int position = index;
    holder.bind(storeList.get(index));
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v ->
            storeFragment.goToPlaceDetailActivity(storeList.get(position)));
}

@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull StoreViewHolder holder) {
    holder.viewDetached();
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return storeList.size();
}

// Override for duplicated bugs
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

// Override for duplicated bugs
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

public List<StoreVO> getStoreList() {
    return storeList;
}

public void setStoreList(List<StoreVO> storeList) {
    this.storeList = storeList;
}

public void clearItems() {
    storeList.clear();
}

public void addItems(List<StoreVO> storeList) {
    this.storeList.addAll(storeList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public StoreFragment getStoreFragment() {
    return storeFragment;
}

public void setStoreFragment(StoreFragment storeFragment) {
    this.storeFragment = storeFragment;
}

class StoreViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private StoreItemListBinding binding;
    private ArrayList<String> urlList;

    StoreViewHolder(StoreItemListBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.urlList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.binding = binding;
        initImageSlider();
    }

    public void bind(StoreVO storeVO) {
        binding.priceTv.setText(String.valueOf(storeVO.getReprMenuPrice()));
        binding.addrTv.setText(storeVO.getAreaDetailNm());
        binding.nameTv.setSelected(true);
        binding.nameTv.setText(storeVO.getStoreNm());
        binding.scoreTv.setText(String.format(Locale.KOREA, "%.1f", storeVO.getStoreScore()));
        addImageSlider(storeVO);
    }

    private void initImageSlider() {
        binding.storeSlider.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimations.FILL); //set indicator animation by using SliderLayout.Animations. :WORM or THIN_WORM or COLOR or DROP or FILL or NONE or SCALE or SCALE_DOWN or SLIDE and SWAP!!
        binding.storeSlider.setScrollTimeInSec(3); //set scroll delay in seconds :
    }

    private void addImageSlider(StoreVO storeVO) {
        generateUrlList(storeVO);
        setSliderViews();
    }

    private void generateUrlList(StoreVO storeVO) {
        urlList.clear();
        if (storeVO.getStoreImageUrlList().size() == 0) {
            String url = CommonUtils.createDefaultImageUrl();
            urlList.add(url);
        } else {
            for (String imageUrl : storeVO.getStoreImageUrlList()) {
                String url = CommonUtils.createStoreImageUrl(storeVO.getStoreSn(), imageUrl);
                urlList.add(url);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setSliderViews() {
        binding.storeSlider.clearSliderViews();
        for (String url : urlList) {
            DefaultSliderView sliderView = new DefaultSliderView(binding.getRoot().getContext().getApplicationContext());
            sliderView.setImageUrl(url);

            sliderView.setImageScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            //sliderView.setOnSliderClickListener(view -> Dlog.e(url));
            //at last add this view in your layout :
            binding.storeSlider.addSliderView(sliderView);
        }
    }

    private void viewDetached() {
        urlList.clear();
        binding.storeSlider.clearSliderViews();
    }
}
```

}

After storeList updated, Text on items of Recylerview was changed but ImageSlider on item was not changed.
I checked that viewDetached() on StoreViewHolder was called but images remaind on previous store item

i was using image sliders in github: https://github.com/smarteist/android-image-slider

what should i do to updated images for imagesliders on recycler-view items???

To simplify my question,
i was using RecyclerView to show items which contains image slider. That image slider load images through URL. After receive new itemList(storeList) from server, itemList(storeList) for RecylerView and URLs in Item(Store) for ImageSlider was changed but not updated on ImageSlider.
Through debugging, i checked that new UrlList was generated and setSliderViews was called but remains previous image 
How do i fix my code to update Images on RecylerView's items?

Comment: Just an FYI, you are creating new `View`s (DefaultSliderView) in `onBindViewHolder()`. Making new memory allocations in `onBindViewHolder()` is bad practice.

Comment: Oh Really?, can you tell me where should i put that codes!?